# Batch File to start .exe when a specific number of files is in monitored folder

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that will trigger an exe whenever there are exactly 4 jpg images in a folder. Afterwards the images should be deleted.

I have got it to work it seems, but the file starts the exe over and over again. I can't seem to wrap my head around what the mistake is.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set counter=0

:loop
cd "c:\JPGfolder\"
for %%B in (*) do set /a counter+=1
echo File Count = !counter!

if !counter! EQU 4 (
for /f "delims=|" %%I in ('DIR "c:\JPGfolder\" /B /O:-D *.jpg') DO (
SET NewestFile=%%I
echo Newest File = "c:\JPGfolder\!NewestFile!"
start "" /w "c:\programs\generate.exe" "c:\JPGfolder\"%NewestFile%
del c:\JPGfolder\*.jpg
GOTO :BREAK
)
)

:BREAK
set /a counter=0

ping -n 2 localhost >nul

) else (
 echo No Files Found
 rem pause
 goto :loop
)
goto :loop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a number of problems with your code. But I cannot see how you are getting the behavior you describe.

1) You are counting all files, but your code to get the newest and delete all only works with .jpg files. Your count should also be restricted to .jpg files.

2) You forgot to use delayed expansion in your START line. But really, there is no need to use an environment value at all. You can simply use `%%I` directly, so delayed expansion is not needed. Also, the entire file path should be enclosed in quotes.

3) You have an extra `)` that closes your IF statement early. The `) ELSE (` and `)` lines are simply ignored, and the lines in between are executed unconditionally. This is an odd quirk of the batch parser. If the parser is looking for a command, and there does not exist an open parentheses block, then `)` and everything after it on that line are simply ignored.

4) If you fix your parentheses by deleting one of the `)` lines, then you still have a problem because you GOTO a label within the complex IF statement. IF ELSE statements are broken by GOTO just as they are with FOR /F statements. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8481558/1012053 for more info.

5) Your CD statement should use the /D option, just in case you are on a different volume. Either that, or use PUSHD instead.

6) Your "No Files Found" message is incorrect - it really should say "File count <> 4"

7) Your algorithm has a fundamental flaw. What if you have 3 .jpg files when your code first checks, and then by the time it checks again, there are 5 .jpg files? Your code will never see a count of 4!

There are also some simplifications possible.

8) Since you have set your current directory to "c:\JPGfolder", you no longer have to explicitly specify the path to the file each time. You can simply use `%%~fI` to get the full path.

9) I would move the initialization of count to below the `:LOOP` label. Then you don't need to worry about setting the value in two places.

I believe the following is the logic you were trying to achieve. Bear in mind, this does not address point 7).

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d "c:\JPGfolder\"

:loop
set counter=0
for %%B in (*.jpg) do set /a counter+=1
echo File Count = %counter%

if %counter% EQU 4 (
  for /f "delims=|" %%I in ('DIR *.jpg /B /O:-D') DO (
    echo Newest File = "%%~fI"
    start "" /w "c:\programs\generate.exe" "%%~fI"
    del *.jpg
    ping -n 2 localhost >nul
    goto :break
  )
) else (
  echo File count <> 4
)
:break
goto :loop
```

The above can be simplified to:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d "c:\JPGfolder\"

:loop
set counter=0
for %%B in (*.jpg) do set /a counter+=1
echo File Count = %counter%

if %counter% EQU 4 (
  for /f "delims=|" %%I in ('DIR *.jpg /B /O:-D') DO (
    echo Newest File = "%%~fI"
    start "" /w "c:\programs\generate.exe" "%%~fI"
    del *.jpg
    ping -n 2 localhost >nul
    goto :loop
  )
)
echo File count <> 4
goto :loop
```

But really, you should probably introduce a delay on every iteration, whether there were 4 .jpg files or not.

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d "c:\JPGfolder\"

:loop
set counter=0
for %%B in (*.jpg) do set /a counter+=1
echo File Count = %counter%

if %counter% EQU 4 (
  for /f "delims=|" %%I in ('DIR *.jpg /B /O:-D') DO (
    echo Newest File = "%%~fI"
    start "" /w "c:\programs\generate.exe" "%%~fI"
    del *.jpg
    goto :break
  )
) else (
  echo File count <> 4
)
:break
ping -n 2 localhost >nul
goto :loop
```

I would not use any of the above code because of point 7). I can't solve that because I do not know what your intent is.

**UPDATE**

It looks to me like you are monitoring a folder for image files, and you want to process every 4th one by some program, in chronological order. All files are deleted after having been received. I recommend moving the files instead of deleting them, just in case something goes wrong and you want to recover some other images. You can always manually delete the saved files at any point.

Your current algorithm demands that the batch script read and process the files faster than images are added to the folder, otherwise you risk missing the count of 4, and no more images are ever processed (my point 7 from above).

Below is a new algorithm that always works, regardless how fast images are added.

Instead of resetting the counter to 0 after each loop, I let the counter grow indefinitely. I use modulo arithmetic to determine when a file represents a multiple of 4 (modulo result is 0). I detect the modulo 0 value by intentionally raising a division by zero error, and the `||` conditionally executes a block of code upon error.

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d "c:\JPGfolder"
md save 2>nul
set counter=0

:LOOP
for /f "delims=|" %%I in ('DIR *.jpg /B /O:-D') do (
  set /a "1/((counter+=1)%%4)" 2>nul || (
    echo Newest File = "%%~fI"
    start "" /w "c:\programs\generate.exe" "%%~fI"
  )
    move "%%I" save >nul
)
ping -n 2 localhost >nul
goto :LOOP
```

Your comment claims you are creating a collage of all 4 images within each iteration. I don't see how that works when you only pass a single file name to generate.exe. But if it is actually what is happening, then the following alternate code should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d "c:\JPGfolder"
2>nul (
  md save
  md working
  del working\*
)
set counter=0

:LOOP
for /f "delims=|" %%I in ('DIR *.jpg /B /O:-D') do (
  move "%%I" working >nul
  set /a "1/((counter+=1)%%4)" 2>nul || (
    echo Newest File = "%%~fI"
    start "" /w "c:\programs\generate.exe" "%%~dpIworking\%%~nxI"
    move working\* save >nul
  )
)
ping -n 2 localhost >nul
goto :LOOP
```

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer that makes a lot of sense. Your last code suggestion works great. Concerning your point 7: Files are coming in from a camera and are being written one at a time into the folder. So I am thinking there won't be a case where there are 5 files in the folder at a time, but I will do further testing to see if that might happen.

Comment: @mohawk - Are you creating a movie using every 4th image (sorted chronologically) within a folder?

Comment: No, it is a photo collage that consists of the 4 last images taken!

Comment: @mohawk - It looks to me to be every 4th image, not the last 4.

Comment: True. The 4th image triggers the .exe which then uses all 4 images.

Comment: @mohawk - How does it use all 4, when you only pass one file as an argument?

Comment: the file names are ongoing numbers. a javascript inside the .exe uses the filename that is passed as an argument, then gets the other file names by incrementing.

Comment: After some testing, it was actually turning out to be problematic if files got written into the folder too fast. I tried your updated code. however, after sweeping the working path, it terminates, error message is "%4) was unexpected at this time". How comes you put %%4? Why is the escape character needed here. Or is the double percent an arithmetic operator in this case? I am not familiar with modular arithmetic.

Comment: @mohawk - I forgot to quote the SET /A expression. The `)` chars must be quoted or escaped to prevent premature closing of the FOR loop block. All fixed now. You need the last set of code. The `%` is the SET /A modulo operator. All percents must be doubled in batch scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic says: If counter = 4 then for each jpg in the folder start exe.

Setting the counter to 0 inside the loop, after you already determined it equalled 4, is not going to stop the loop.

You also have an incomplete IF statement, caused by an extra closing bracket (before the :BREAK) that's messing with your ELSE statement.

Hope that helps!

Comment: No, the `GOTO :BREAK` stops the loop. The IF statement is not inomplete, it is just terminated early. The `) ELSE (` line and `)` line are simply ignored because there are no open parentheses blocks. So all the lines in between are executed unconditionally (this is a peculiar feature of batch parsing).

Comment: @dbenham and the last goto :loop starts it again.

Comment: @LPChip - I was referring to the FOR /F loop. But now I see that there could be confusion over which loop we are talking about. The final `GOTO :LOOP` is clearly executed unconditionally, so it should be obvious that the GOTO loop is never ending.